# Mroonga on Mariadb Primary Key Insert error

Tags: mariadb

I keep on getting duplicate primary key error when trying to insert into my Mroonga table on MariaDB 10.0.19. Does anyone know what might be the cause?

SQL:

```
    insert into tbl_mroonga select pk_id, keyword from tbl_inno;
```

Create table:

```
    create table tbl_mroonga (
    'PK_ID' int(11) not null default 0,
    'Keyword' varchar(191) null default null,
    primary key (`pk_id`),
    fulltext index ('keyword')) Engine=MROONGA;

    create table tbl_inno (
    'PK_ID' int(11) not null default 0,
    'Keyword' varchar(191) null default null,
    primary key (`pk_id`),
    fulltext index ('keyword')) Engine=INNODB;
```

I'm inserting about 3.5million rows from tbl_inno to tbl_mroonga and it fails at around 400K rows. I've tried it with "select distinct" and "group by pk_id" and still it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: This link may help: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment/

Comment: `Primary Key` are distinct/unique, `select distinct` & `group by pk_id` will have no effect. 1 - Try creating a fresh table using `Engine=MROONGA`. 2 - or see if `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tbl_mroonga.keyword = tbl_inno.keyword` phrase helps. PS: I've no exp with MROONGA in person.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in `mysqld.err`?

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop that copies over 10K rows at a time.  Use something like (example of the 13th chunk):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_mroonga
SELECT pk_id, keyword
    FROM tbl_inno
    WHERE pk_id >  120000
      AND pk_id <= 130000
```

and `COMMIT` after each chunk.